# Adding / removing the additional fees to a customer via Subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

Depending on some conditions, I want to charge a customer an additional fee or vise versa - add money to their account or just don't charge them at all.
They're all **subscribed** to to a certain plain. To be able to change the fees, I have to play with `account_balance`

```
https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer

account_balance
An integer amount in cents that is the starting account balance for your customer. A negative amount represents a credit that will be used before attempting any charges to the customer’s card; a positive amount will be added to the next invoice.
```

but

```
https://support.stripe.com/questions/subscription-setup-fees

For example, if you have a $10 monthly plan called ten-monthly, but want to charge your customer a $5 setup fee, this API call to create a customer would work:

curl -i https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers \
   -u sk_test_mkGsLqEW6SLnZa487HYfJVLf: \
   -d "card[number]=4242424242424242" \
   -d "card[exp_month]=11" \
   -d "card[exp_year]=2015" \
   -d "card[cvc]=314" \
   -d plan=ten-monthly \
   -d account_balance=500
```

However, these 2 are at odds with each other: the first one says "A negative amount represents a credit" whereas the 2nd one uses a positive number 500 to add the additional fees which is also considered to be a credit (when I take a credit in a bank, I owe money).

So, which one is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look at your second example it will set the account balance with `500` in cents which would be $5 meaning that the customer owes **you** $5 when it is created. Since you are creating a customer and setting him up on a $10 monthly plan, the first invoice will be for $15 which is $10 for the plan to which is added the current account balance of the user so $5.

If you wanted to give a $4 credit to your customer so that his first invoice was $6 instead of $10 for example, you would set his account balance to `-400` (-$4) when creating the customer.

Another solution for this set-up fee is to use [Invoice Items](https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoiceitems) as the docs say:

> Sometimes you want to add a charge or credit to a customer but only actually charge the customer's card at the end of a regular billing cycle. This is useful for combining several charges to minimize per-transaction fees or having Stripe tabulate your usage-based billing totals.

I find this easier to work with since it appears on the invoice directly instead of having to look at the customer's account balance to understand what happens.

If you want to use this solution, you could read the guide on the [subscriptions doc](https://stripe.com/docs/guides/subscriptions#changing-the-amount-billed) but the idea would be something like this

- Create your customer (no balance)
- Create an Invoice Item for the plan set-up fee (or the credit)
- Subscribe your customer to the plan

The first invoice would be created (and closed immediately) and would automatically pick up the Invoice Item you created.

For the next invoices, if you want to add credit or charges to your customer's subscription you could listen for the `invoice.created` webhook and create Invoice Items at that point for the invoice. The reason it needs to be different for the first invoice is that it is always automatically closed so you can't add Invoice Items to it in the webhook

Comment: I'll go with "account_balance". How can I do that? From the documentation it's not clear whether I have to update only customer.account_balance or subscription too somehow.

Comment: Just use the account balance when creating the customer or updating the customer, this is not linked to subscriptios (though subscriptions uses the balance when charging for an invoice)

Comment: That would depend on the language you're using I guess, in PHP you'd set `$my_customer-> account_balance` property on the instance and then call `$my_customer->save()`

Comment: if case of Subscription, does the user get charged automatically each month? Meaning, once I've created a subscription by `stripe_customer.subscriptions.create(plan: plan_id)`, I **don't** have to charge them manually (by writing the code) at the end of the month, right? They'll be charged by stripe automatically.

Comment: Yes that's what subscriptions are for. Once you put a customer on a monthly plan he gets automatically charged every month. So if you subscribe him today (23rd of December) he'll get charged in a month (23rd of January).

Comment: look at this https://support.stripe.com/questions/metered-subscription-billing, it says "Set the account_balance when creating a customer or updating a customer's subscription." But according to you, it should be "updating a customer", shouldn't it? `customer.account_balance = 123; customer.save`

Comment: I don't see a way to update the `account_balance` when updating the subscription so I guess it could be just a confusing sentence

Comment: thanks, one more question: how do make such the subscription "So if you subscribe him today (23rd of December) he'll get charged in a month (23rd of January)" - I'd like to charge them at the end of the month -  31 December and 31 January and so on.

Comment: With trial period and or this: https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-can-i-change-the-billing-cycle-of-a-subscription

Comment: look https://stripe.com/docs/guides/subscriptions#adding-invoice-items - when I receive a webhook with the type == 'invoice.created', how do I know to what invoice to add the invoice items I want to add? I can retrieve the customer by customer email, but how can I retrieve the invoice to which I want to add the invoice items?